# EMF radiation from an open AC circuit

Tags: ac, emf

When I pass my EMF radiation meter near an electricity cable (a cable that is connected to the home mains), it shows me that there is a radiation.

But if there is an extension cable for example, and nothing is connected to it, there is still radiation measured from the EMF meter.

How it can be? It is an open circuit so the current is 0, so how there is a movement of electrons?

Comment: Imagine two long wires in parallel to each other. They are unconnected at the far end from you. But at the near end you supply a rapidly swinging voltage difference across that end. Do you imagine ***nothing*** at all taking place in the wires? Or do you imagine ***something*** happening? If ***something***, then what? And how would this "appear" from the perspective of the driving circuit at your end? And is it at all possible in your mind that some lost energy, not all of it but at least some, might be lost to affects caused to nearby and far away matter?

Comment: Also, read [this](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_28.html). You should find it interesting.

Comment: It's not radiation, it's voltage - does that put your mind at rest?